# Which file Linux server is writing to?

Tags: linux

Server is actively writing into some file. How to find the file which is receiving heavy i/o ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try iotop. On Debian/Ubuntu:

```
apt-get install iotop
```

Then `iotop` will show you I/O per process. You can then inspect the file descriptors for the process in question if in need of more data - for example with `ls -l /proc/<PID>/fd` or `lsof -p <PID>`.

Comment: It needs kernel support though.

Comment: @romaninsh good point, I think it requires kernels >2.6.20 (stock).

Comment: Could not run iotop as some of the requirements are not met:
    - Linux >= 2.6.20 with
      - I/O accounting support (CONFIG_TASKSTATS,CONFIG_TASK_DELAY_ACCT, CONFIG_TASK_IO_ACCOUNTING)

Comment: Which kernel version/distribution you're running? If you're running something older than 2.6.20 and you're serving something there you should really upgrade if at all possible - kernels older than 2.6.22 if I remember correctly have a blatant security hole (privilege scalation) very easy to exploit.

Comment: @Eduardo Ivanec - There are numerous patched kernels older than 2.6.22. RHEL4 for example, is 2.6.9, and RHEL 5 at 2.6.18; both safe and supported.

Comment: This can't be up-to-date RHEL5, because i/o accounting was backported to it.

Comment: @JimB - that's true of course, I was assuming a system not up-to-date with security patches based primarily on the impression they are more frequent amongst systems with old kernels.

Answer (score 3):

Since I/O accounting isn't available, maybe you could use a solution based on inotify. This is included in the kernel since 2.6.13. Using *inotifywatch* from [inotify-tools](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools) you can watch for changes to any file on your system with `inotifywatch -r /`. It will take a long time to 
establish all the watches, and you may have to increase */proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches*. Inotifywatch will run until you interrupt it with *ctrl-c*. After you interrupt, for each file that was accessed it will statistics on the operations that were performed. For example

```
$ inotifywatch -r ~
Establishing watches...
Finished establishing watches, now collecting statistics.
total  access  modify  close_write  open  moved_from  moved_to  create  filename
6099   0       6092    2            2     1           1         1       /home/example/foo
```